# return a list that contains the last vowel phoneme and subsequent consonant phoneme(s)

Tags: python, python-3.x

So i was working on this question

A vowel phoneme is a phoneme whose last character is 0, 1, or 2. As examples, the word BEFORE (B IH0 F AO1 R) contains two vowel phonemes and the word GAP (G AE1 P) has one.

The parameter represents a list of phonemes. The function is to return a list that contains the last vowel phoneme and subsequent consonant phoneme(s) in the given list of phonemes. The empty list is to be returned if the list of phonemes does not contain a vowel phoneme.

Comment: What is `pattern`? You are not checking anywhere if the last character is a 0, 1, or 2.

Answer (score 4):

```
def last_phonemes(phoneme_list):
    """ (list of str) -> list of str

    Return the last vowel phoneme and subsequent consonant phoneme(s) in
    phoneme_list.

    >>> last_phonemes(['AE1', 'B', 'S', 'IH0', 'N', 'TH'])
    ['IH0', 'N', 'TH']
    >>> last_phonemes(['IH0', 'N'])
    ['IH0', 'N']
    >>> last_phonemes(['B', 'S'])
    []
    """
    for i, phoneme in reversed(list(enumerate(phoneme_list))):
        if phoneme[-1] in '012':
            return phoneme_list[i:]
    return []
```

**EDIT** explanation

You want to iterate over the phoneme_list in [reversed](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reversed) order. When you find the first item that contains the '0' character, then you want to slice the original list (you got the slice part right in your code). You will need the index to make the slicing, so you [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) the phoneme_list before reversing.

Comment: `A vowel phoneme is a phoneme whose last character is 0, 1, or 2.`

Comment: It should be `if phoneme[-1] in '012':`